# How to generate all possible combinations of a 2d array in Python, if a value in this array can be between 0 and 255

Tags: python, arrays, python-itertools

So i have an empty 4*4 array, values in it can be between 0 and 255, i want to generate all possible states of this array, for example, one of the states is:

```
 [0, 0, 0, 0] 
 [0, 0, 0, 0] 
 [0, 0, 0, 0] 
 [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and the other is:

```
[245, 241, 124, 53]
[124, 11, 45, 31]
[44, 0, 124, 3]
[1, 30, 123, 31]
```

Is it possible to do with itertools? And if it is, how do i do it

Comment: The total number of possible states here is `255 ^ 16 = 3.1962658e+38`. Are you sure you want to generate all of them?

Comment: It's 256^16 (0-255 inclusive), which is equal to 2^128, which is the number of possible keys in a 128-bit encryption algorithm. Just for comparison.

Comment: Since what you want to do is computationally infeasible, perhaps you can tell us why you're trying to do it, and we can help you find a better way.

Comment: The array in the question just an example, i want to know the exact way to do this

Comment: I am sure Python is up to this, though. It is not a technical problem.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, i just realised that the thing i initially wanted to do is impossible (generating all possible 8*8 grayscale images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of combinations that you are requesting here is `255^16=3.1962658*10^38` which is a very big number.

Given that 1TB = 10^12 bytes and the clock spead of CPU is 4GHz, it will take as number of molecules in a sugar cube number of storage devices and 10 billion times the age of the universe to acquire and list all of them!

**In short**: you can't.

You can do something like

```
import numpy as np
i=0
while i < 10000:
    currentstate=256*np.floor(np.rand(4,4))
/* ... do something with current state */
```

and randomly sample the states.